# Parameter not passing from controll class to DP class Report AX 2012

Tags: reporting-services, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have created a RDP report without query , only with classes: contract, controller data provider and I am having issues the parameters passing to rdp class, in batch dialog I take the customer order selected when I click ok nothing appears it doesnt pass the value to dp class(it is suppozed to show the sales order related to that customer).
Any suggestion or it is just a AX service problem ?

Comment: Did you decorate your parm methods with `DataMemberAttribute`?

Comment: Yes,I did ,also checked similar reports and everythings seem right

Comment: Have you performed a CIL compile?

Comment: I thikn you should provide your controller and contract and RDP classes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prePromptModifyContract` method of your controller class to update dialog fields.

> Provides the opportunity to modify the contract before the dialog is shown to the user.

> This method is invoked for interactive scenarios.
> This method is not invoked for batch scenarios. This means any member variables instantiated in this method will not be available for the lifetime of the controller in batch scenarios

See also [Using Controller Class in Developing SSRS Reports in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606184700/https://www.dynamics101.com/using-controller-class-developing-ssrs-reports-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/).

If you have a report query, then [retrieve it](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/135732) in `prePromptModifyContract` or `preRunModifyContract` method of your controller class:

```
Query q = this.getFirstQuery();
```

Then update the query adding ranges.

```
q.datasourceTable(tableNum(xx)).addRange(fieldNum(xx,ff)).value(queryValue(123));
```

Comment: yes,I used prePromptModifyContract  but my problem was that I had pased the parameter twice in different places ,thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's been years, but I don't see any answer accepted - so will suggest an answer.

"You will need to refresh the data source on the report itself as well. As the parameters aren't refreshed there unless you manually go and refresh the data source on the report".

I hope this helps somebody else as well.

Thanks,
Rizwan